# Is there a way to get mobile phone account in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm developing an iOS app, but i need to identify the user who made the request to the web server.

I read on the internet that i cannot retrieve user's phone number, is there anything else that  i can use to identify user?

I need something "legally-valid" (**I mean that if the user do something illegal with my app, I should be able to track it down**)

I cannot just "let user type its phone number" because i need that it's really true. I cannot risk that user type the number of someone else

Comment: I dont know exact what you want?I can suggest ->  Use UUID & store it NSUserDefaults if needed & use this identify each user uniquely till the app is alive(I mean till it app is uninstalled on iOS device). see if it helps u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the phone number; you just have to ask the user for it.

In the past, people have used the device UDID for this sort of thing. The UDID is deprecated now, and new devices may not even have one. You can search on UDID to find out what people are using in place of the UDID -- in particular, look for the OpenUDID and SecureUDID projects. In some cases the device's wifi MAC address can be used, but that brings with it some of the same privacy concerns as the UDID.

You can also just generate and store a globally unique identifier. Search for "GUID" to learn how to do this. With a GUID, you can be virtually certain that the identifier is unique.

It's not clear what you mean by "legally valid". Is that "valid" with respect to privacy laws, cryptography laws, communications regulations, or something else? And in what country?

Comment: I mean that if the user do something illegal, I should be able to track it down (eg. via phone number)

Comment: There's no public API that would really help there. You could create some sort of registration process of your own that includes as much validation as you want, but you'd have to do the work there.

Comment: **you just have to ask the user for it.** - and your app will be rejected on review because this behavior contradicts with [this](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#privacy) requirement

Comment: @CAMOBAP There's no obvious prohibition in §17 on asking the user for phone number or anything else. On the contrary, that section says that you need the user's permission to collect anything, and that you can't *require* that the user provide the information in order to access the app's functionality. I agree that the OP's requirement for a unique user identifier probably won't fly, but AFAIK there's nothing wrong with asking the user for info, and in fact many apps do exactly that.